# readline history not working

Tags: command-line, readline, chicken-scheme

Okay, so Chicken-scheme has this great [readline](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/readline) egg that can be used to add history, tab completion, and other sane features to the `csi` command-line environment.  However, I can't seem to get it to work *correctly*, that is it *only works the first time I start `csi` up after creating a new history file*.

I've checked the documentation for the egg and other similar eggs such as [linenoise](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/linenoise) and [parley](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/parley), but neither of them offer tab-completion or any advice on how to address this shortcoming of readline.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```scm
(current-input-port (make-gnu-readline-port))
(gnu-history-install-file-manager
  (string-append (or (get-environment-variable "HOME") ".") "/.csi_history"))
```

**NOTE**

While writing this I think I may have figured out the problem or at least part of the problem.  The problem, I think, lies in the fact that I'm *installing* a history file; as in it only works for the *first installation*?

However, my attempt to cook my own readline `file-manager` setup makes it so that gnu readline *never* writes to the history file, however, it will *read from it*.

```scm
(current-input-port (make-gnu-readline-port))
(let ((histfile (string-append (or (get-environment-variable "HOME") ".")
  "/.csi_history")))
  (and (file-exists? histfile) (gnu-readline-read-history histfile))
  (gnu-readline-append-history histfile))
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: Looks like you are using a legacy version of the Chicken readline API. Try updating readline and your `.csirc` according to the wiki.

Comment: @nwk, I forgot that I posted this question.  It has since been answered in the chicken-users mailing list.  Also, I'm the maintainer of the Chicken Readline egg, so I'm well aware of the update, lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that in my `~/.zshrc` file I had an alias for `csi` that called `csi` with `rlwrap`:

```bash
alias csi='rlwrap csi'
```

Calling `rlwrap` on `csi` was causing `csi` to use `rlwrap`'s history instead of the *built-in* history provided by the readline egg.

Answer (score 0):

readline is deprecated in chicken scheme solution is to install linenoise

and put this in your .csirc:

```
(import linenoise)
(current-input-port (make-linenoise-port))

(set-history-length! 300)

(load-history-from-file ".linenoise-history")

(let loop ((expr (linenoise "> ")))
              (cond ((equal? expr "bye")
                             (save-history-to-file ".linenoise-history")
                             "Bye!")
                    (else
                        (display (eval (read (open-input-string expr))))
                        (newline)
                        (history-add expr)
                        (loop (linenoise "> ")))))
```